# Geth client: how to disable ipv6?

Tags: go-ethereum

By default, the Geth client appears to listen to both IPv6 and IPv4. There doesn't appears to be a command line option to disable one of them. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there may be an easier way to specify the one you want, but you could always just remove the address of whichever protocol you don't want from any interfaces on the host.  If there is no address to listen on, it can't have a listener, right?  How you do that is very platform-specific, but it shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Thanks. However, just because ipv6 is unwanted by geth, doesn't mean it's unwanted for the whole system.