# How to force geth to use ipv4 instead of ipv6

Tags: go-ethereum, connections, geth-clique, ports

I'm trying to configure geth on Redhat7 and facing an issue while connecting nodes from the two servers.
There are three validator nodes on each machines and ports(30303, 30304, 30305) are allowed. But when I check peerCounts, it's showing 2 instead of 5.

I'm connecting these nodes using `static-nodes.json` file.

After checking port details, I found that geth uses ipv6 address. In order to check the actual issue. I want to make it to run with ipv4

[image]

Is there any way to force geth to use ipv4?

Answer (score 1):

You question same as this [Geth client: how to disable ipv6?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30995/geth-client-how-to-disable-ipv6). Try swith off using of ipv6 maybe it helps localize problem. Geth hasn't special args to control version of used ipv.